# About time complexity of arraylist and linkedlist

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, time-complexity

In page 290 of the book [data structures and algorithms](https://www.amazon.ca/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Michael-Goodrich/dp/1118771338/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1524066312&sr=8-2&keywords=data%20structures%20and%20algorithms%20in%20java) it is mentioned that complexity of remove(i) for arraylist is O(1). My first question is why not O(n)? It is also mentioned add(i,e) for linked list is O(n), so my second question is why not O(min(i,n-i))?

Finally, my 3rd question is the reason the complexity is mentioned as O(min(i,n-i)) is it due to being a doubly linked list, meaning we could either traverse from beginning (i) or end (n-i)?

Comment: `remove(i)` for ArrayList is definitely not `O(1)`. Can you include the context in your post? I don't have the sixth edition, but I found a pdf of the fourth edition which talks about arraylist based implementations of stacks around that page number. In that case, popping an element by removing it from the end of the ArrayList is in fact `O(1)`

Comment: @thatotherguy please see this link: https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Java/Data%20Structures%20and%20Algorithms%20in%20Java%20%286th%20ed.%29%20%5BGoodrich%2C%20Tamassia%20%26%20Goldwasser%202014-01-28%5D.pdf

Comment: I see. It says `java.util.List.remove(i)` for ArrayList is `O(1)`,
and for LinkedList is `O(min{i,n−i})`. This is just wrong. I had a look at the errata and it's not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is debatable. When you remove the last element in an ArrayList, it's constant, but for a middle element, you need to shift all successor elements to the left. Java does that using System.arrayCopy(), a very fast native routine for copying arrays, but even that method is clearly O(n), not constant, so I'm inclined to agree with you. It's different for an insert, where the amortized cost of resizing arrays up to the required index is averaged out to a constant factor, so add() is O(1).

The second one could be implemented that way, but it isn't. Remove starts from the beginning only. I'm guessing the choice was made to reduce accidents by unsynchronized access.

Finally, in notations of Big-O complexity, less significant factors are discarded, so O(min(i,n-i)) is actually equivalent to O(n), even though the real world tells us that the former would certainly be an optimization.

Comment: Thanks. Please note the second question is about adding not removing. And in 3rd question, I would like to confirm if my understanding is correct, that if we search from beginning it is i, and from end it is n.